# Spring boot : download csv file data with special character

Tags: java

I have a button ,when I click it, I want to download a csv file.
When my csv file has data, 'big apple.'. There is no problem generating it.

But when i have data like `big , apple.`  with a comma,   The file fails to get generated. 
How do i get my csv file generated with special characters?

```
window.location.href = '/coaGlCsv?coaId='+coaType+'';


@RequestMapping(value = "/coaGlCsv", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody 
public void getCsv(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam("coaId") String coaId)  {
        System.out.println("Generate excel"); 
        response.setContentType("text/csv");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + reportName);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("date","name");
        out.println("12-07-2019","big apple.");
}
```

Comment: Hiow is this related to Java, jQuery or Spring? BTW, excel is not CSV.

Comment: Corrected the mistake.  it's related to spring boot + java because my backend was trying to generate it

Comment: OK. How is the output wrong? What do you get, what do you expect?

Comment: what's the error ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean

> file fails to get generated

Can you download file from the server? Does server throw an exception? If so - provide it in your question.

Double quotes can solve your problem with data with a comma. [Take a look at csv format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules) Use `"big , apple"`